# Is it a good programming practice to call invalidate() inside onDraw()?

Tags: android, ondraw

1. Is it a good programming practice to call `invalidate()` inside `onDraw()`?

As per my understanding, calling `invalidate()` inside `onDraw()` is expensive and is not required if there is no change to the canvas.

1. Is `invalidate()` equivalent to an asynchronous version of `onDraw()`?

As per my understanding, they are equivalent. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Only call `invalidate()` if your data has changed and needs to be redrawn.  You generally don't do this in `onDraw()`, because at that point you are drawing your current data, not changing it.  (There are some cases where you may want to do this, such as for running animations, but generally I would recommend instead using a delayed message to control your own timing of the updates.)

Comment: Is there any chance calling `invalidate()` from `onDraw()` when running an animation (which is what I want to do) can cause a stack overflow, or is the relationship indirect?

Comment: @AndrewWyld see [ExplosionAnimator.draw](https://github.com/tyrantgit/ExplosionField/blob/master/explosionfield/src/main/java/tyrantgit/explosionfield/ExplosionAnimator.java), the method ExplosionAnimator.draw will be called by View.onDraw, and it call invalidate() directly. On my phone, calling invalidate will make the explosion animation smoother. postInvalidate sometimes cause the animation drop frames.